# Adjusting position of horizontal line in fraction

Tags: math-mode, context

My inline fractions are typeset as below

[image]

but to my eyes the line is a bit too low?  Is it possible to raise the line y position a bit?

Comment: the space under 2 allows `\frac{y}{x}` to have the same layout.

Comment: It is easier for people to help if you give a complete compilable example, and tell us how you compile your document.

Comment: Oh it didn't add the context tag for some reason.

Comment: @avid - The `context` tag is for documents that employ the ConTeXt format (as opposed to, say, the LaTeX and Plain-TeX formats). Are you saying you're using ConTeXt to compile your documents? If so, please provide a compilable example.

Comment: @avid, if you need an example of a question that has sufficient details for people to help, take a look at some of [my questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2148/dave-jarvis?tab=questions&sort=activity), they all follow the same structure and pretty much all of them have an answer.